# Testing Haskell code : separating state

Tags: haskell, testing

I am writing a online game in haskell..
My GameEngine is in `statemonad` so it is simple to test and we have written properties for it. It's just bliss.

However, server has a list of users which is in `MVar`. [Server.hs](https://github.com/nilenso/tronkell/blob/master/src/Tronkell/Server/Server.hs) There are a lot of threads running around. One game thread, tcp and websocket threads, each client on its own thread etc. All of them talks with Channels.

The problem is with `testing some user workflow` ; like

1. user joins and quits immediately even before game starts
2. user leaves in between of game;
3. user quits the game and so on..

User workflow is coupled with all the threads which are in `IO()`.
I tried writing unit tests on functions by passing channels (prefilled with values). But they looked very fragile. Every time i change the code, its hard to understand why test failed. Its not very bad but i am in search of better way.

How can i test my workflows ? Can i use some other kind of programming abstractions ?

I am open to all kind of suggestions (FRP / free monads : I do not know any of them.. but if they solve the problem i am ready to learn.).

Relevant code :

```
data Server = Server { serverGameConfig :: Game.GameConfig
                 , serverUsers      :: MVar (M.Map UserID User)
                 , networkChans     :: NetworkChans
                 , serverChan       :: TChan InMessage
                 , clientsChan      :: Chan OutMessage
                 , internalChan     :: Chan ServerSignals
}

runClient :: UserID -> Chan InMessage -> Server -> IO ()
runClient uId clientChan server@Server{..} = do
  let (_, clientSpecificOutChan) = networkChans
  writeChan clientSpecificOutChan $ (uId, ServerMsg "Take a nick name : ")
  msg <- readChan clientChan
  let nick = case msg of
               PlayerName _ name -> Just name
               _ -> Nothing

  case nick of
    Nothing -> runClient uId clientChan server
    Just _ -> do
      let user = User uId nick Waiting
      failedToAdd <- modifyMVar serverUsers $ \users ->
        -- for player we still have name as id ; so keep it unique.
        if isNickTaken users nick
        then return (users, True)
        else return (M.insert uId user users, False)

      if failedToAdd
      then runClient uId clientChan server
      else do atomically $ writeTChan serverChan $ PlayerJoined uId
              writeChan clientSpecificOutChan $ (uId, ServerMsg $ "Hi.. " ++ T.unpack (fromJust nick) ++ ".. Type ready when you are ready to play.. quit to quit.")
              fix $ \loop -> do m <- readChan clientChan
                                case m of
                                 PlayerReady _ -> playClient uId clientChan server
                                 PlayerExit  _ -> atomically $ writeTChan serverChan $ PlayerExit uId
                                 _ -> loop
  where
    isNickTaken users nick = any (\u -> nick == userNick u) users

cleanString :: String -> String
cleanString = reverse . dropWhile (\c -> c == '\n' || c == '\r') . reverse

playClient :: UserID -> Chan InMessage -> Server -> IO ()
playClient clientId inChan Server{..} = do
    -- because every client wants same copy of the message, duplicate channel.
  outClientChan <- dupChan clientsChan
  writeChan outClientChan $ ServerMsg "Waiting for other players to start the game...!!!"

  let (_, clientSpecificOutChan) = networkChans
  writer <- forkIO $ forever $ do
    outMsg <- readChan outClientChan
    writeChan clientSpecificOutChan (clientId, outMsg)

  clientInternalChan <- dupChan internalChan

  -- otherwise gameready msg for this second client joining is lost.
  atomically $ writeTChan serverChan $ PlayerReady clientId

  -- block on ready-signal from server-thread to start the game.
  signal <- readChan clientInternalChan
  case signal of
    GameReadySignal config players -> writeChan outClientChan $ GameReady config players

  writeList2Chan outClientChan [ ServerMsg "Here.. you go!!!"
                               , ServerMsg "Movements: type L for left , R for right, Q for quit... enjoy." ]

  -- todo: for this functionality we would need to use TChan for userChan/inChan
  -- hFlush clientHdl

  fix $ \loop ->
    do
      msg <- readChan inChan
      case msg of
        PlayerExit _ -> void $ writeChan outClientChan $ ServerMsg "Sayonara !!!"
        _ -> atomically (writeTChan serverChan msg) >> loop

  killThread writer

  atomically $ writeTChan serverChan (PlayerExit clientId)
```

As you can see, users are in MVar.. (TVar does not matter as only one thread writes). The problem is testing.

How can i structure my code such that `workflow logic` in `runClient` and `playClient` can be separated for testing ?

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question, as you might close your GitHub repository and thus make your question invalid. Also, your question is kind of open-ended. You're almost asking for a tutorial, which is off-topic. A [mcve] can tackle down your problem to a fraction of its size (which can easily answered) and still provide valuable information for you and future readers.

Comment: @Zeta You are right.. i have included two functions and i am now asking for right way to structure this code .. Is this fine ?

Comment: I guess. Note that, **if** your code works, your question is eligible for [CodeReview.SE], which is suitable for questions with a lot of code. But that's an aside. Note that your example isn't what I would call "minimal", by the way. But it's probably hard to come up with something that shows your problem in  a short way.

Comment: You are using the `IO` to manage state which makes testing stateful code difficult. You should use something like `StateT Server IO` instead of `IO`. Your issue, however, seems to be testing user interaction in particular - the difficulty will likely be writing to the appropriate handle at the exact correct time, to e.g. disconnect a user before they complete connecting. If this is the case, you should abstract out the user interaction code into a typeclass, e.g. `class UserInteractionMonad m where pollMsg :: m Message; sendMsg :: Message -> m ()`.

Comment: Furthermore, the question "How can i structure my code such that workflow logic in runClient and playClient can be separated ?" isn't exactly clear, and it doesn't seem to be the same question as "How can i test my workflows ?" - you should limit yourself to one question per question.

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks for suggestions. i would read about `StateT Server IO`. About 2 questions : i would say that i want to `separate out workflow logic` with the aim to be able to test it.

Comment: @AshishNegi I see, you think you have a mixing of concerns and you would like to reason about each separately. Your issue is that everything is just `IO` - so you can't distinguish it. Make separate classes for everything which you consider a 'separate logic' - for your actual game, you instantiate everything with `IO`, and for testing, you have a custom type which allows you to test each 'logic' as you wish (or perhaps multiple custom types!). See my prev. comment and `UserInteractionMonad` - and [this](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/) may interest you.

Comment: Also note that you'll have to change your datatype - `Chan` and `TChan` only work with actual `IO` and testing these is much too much work (especially in conjunction with async. IO over the network). You can have e.g `class MonadChan m c | m -> c where newChan :: m (c a); ...` and then make the 'chan' a parameter in the type: `data Server chan tchan = Server { ..., serverChan :: tchan InMessage, clientsChan :: chan OutMessage, ... }`

Comment: You can test code that lives in IO. It's not clear to me what you're asking

Comment: @jberryman i am asking for the strategies that can help me in moving logic out of `IO` .. user2407038 has given some suggestions.. if you have any other pattern that i can follow that can help in separating things out at higher level, it would be helpful.

Comment: hi.. i tried the suggestions; but i found that it was either too much work and also little orthogonal to what i wanted. I did not wanted to abstract network/chans but test workflow.. finally i moved (most of) workflow logic out in a pure function and wrote tests for that..  https://github.com/ashishnegi/tronkell/commit/dbbe8b5da98eb11c73bca009553dd31cb33cc696#diff-e093df5fb77651bca1f325e5e2d15f69R239 and tests : https://github.com/ashishnegi/tronkell/commit/c23211851f8cb83b8dcfdb3d3e88c14620ebe5f6#diff-1c8164ce9e43c5b4494524dd89ad4e03R26 Does it look OK ? or is it `poor man's` state mangment.